# Change where setuptools downloads .egg files

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I'm new to Python, but when I use setuptools to install .eggs for a project, it places them all in the current working directory (top level directory of the project). This litters the directory and makes it difficult to move them all together, separately from the rest of the project.

Is there a way to have the .eggs download to a subdirectory?

EDIT | @Kos suggests using virtualenv. Oddly this still seems to download .egg directories outside of the virtual env.

```
(.virtualenv)default@232f7f34a1dd:/projects/python/tmp/sql$ which python
/projects/python/tmp/sql/.virtualenv/bin/python
running test)default@232f7f34a1dd:/projects/python/tmp/sql$ python setup.py test
Searching for nose
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/nose/
Best match: nose 1.3.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/nose/nose-1.3.3.tar.gz#md5=42776061bf5206670cb819176dc78654
Processing nose-1.3.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-0eX3mf/nose-1.3.3/setup.cfg
Running nose-1.3.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-0eX3mf/nose-1.3.3/egg-dist-tmp-MJ1xDk
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/.build'

Installed /projects/python/tmp/sql/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
(.virtualenv)default@232f7f34a1dd:/projects/python/tmp/sql$
```

Notice "Installed /projects/python/tmp/sql/nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg" ? That should be somewhere under "Installed /projects/python/tmp/sql/.virtualenv/.....".

Answer (score 1):

You'd normally create a [`virtualenv`](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) in any place of your choice and install packages there.

Comment: Thanks! I'd heard of virtualenv but had no idea what it did.

Comment: Hmm. I installed virtualenv through pip, then created a `.virtualenv` directory under my project. I put .virtualenv/bin on my $PATH and verified that `which python` showed `.virtualenv/bin/python`. But when I run `python setup.py test`, "nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg" gets downloaded to my current working directory (the project directory), not the virtualenv.

Comment: did you activate your virtualenv first?

Comment: I did indeed :) See my edit in my question (prompt reflects activation). I just added 'docker-py' to `install_requires` too and that has downloaded a good 4-5 eggs to my current directory. Seems like setuptools is ignoring the virtualenv or something. Or am I missing some essential environment variables?

Comment: Poking through the source code of setuptools, it just downloads them to the current directory. This is hard coded. https://github.com/jaraco/setuptools/blob/11b6828342b5f34bc593d49b0b13dc23a2eb7a2d/setuptools/dist.py#L330